# The parameter x has not been declared

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am very new to programming and I always receive this error when defining functions:

```
The parameter IPWM_int has not been declared
```

There is no return type for the function, but it does not give any errors.

Here is the function that causes the problem (this is out of main() function):

```
int IntToASCII(IPWM_int)
{
    uint8_t i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        IPWM_string[i]=0x30;
    }

    sprintf(IPWM_string,"%5d", IPWM_int);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read more about how functions are declared in C, especially how arguments are declared. To start with, all arguments needs a type, something which is missing in your function, as well as the return type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just edited my code with return type. The code I copied from also did not have this argument types, but it did not give any compiling errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function definition here is presumably (based on the `%d` formatting specifier and the variable name):

```
int IntToASCII(int IPWM_int)
```

The only way that this function definition could compile is if it were in ANSI C, and looked like this:

```
int IntToASCII(IPWM_int)
int IPWM_int;
{
    [...]
```

Perhaps this explains why the code you adapted this from compiled?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the argument `IPWM_int` a type. It looks like you want `IPWM_int` to be the name of the parameter here so if this parameter is an `int`, for example, you would have:

```
int IntToASCII(int IPWM_int)
{
    uint8_t i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    { 
        IPWM_string[i]=0x30;
    }

    sprintf(IPWM_string,"%5d", IPWM_int);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int IntToASCII(int IPWM_int)
            // ^^^ is required at function declaration and definition.
```

syntax:

```
return-type functionName(dataType arg1, datatype arg2, ....)
{
  //function body
}
```